# SonarQube & Aura Framework

Tags: sonarqube, aura-framework

Can SonarQube scan the code (Components and events) written in Aura Framework and provide the results as required.
Is there any plugin for the same IF not how can we achieve it.?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's composed of JavaScript and Java, yes. The base distribution comes with those language plugins, so all you'll need to do is [download](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/) and [set up](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Get+Started+in+Two+Minutes) a server and start [scanning](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner) your code.

Comment: Can we use any out of the box plugin or do we need to write any custom rules to achieve it.??

Comment: No. See expanded answer.

Comment: I have seen in Aura app's javascript files consists Aura Context such as $A etc (similar to $J in j query). 
Could it be a cause of concern while scanning the Code with default sonarway profile. Since it is different context all together than plain  javascript.

Comment: There is a jQuery-related configuration that might help. For a deeper discussion you should probably head over to the Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube